# Break string into keyword list from scientific article keywords

Tags: python

I am trying to split each keyword from a keywords string using comma as separate character, but chemical names are also named with comma, How can I identify chemical names and not separate the name?

Here's some examle:

```
keywords_string1 = "Forecasting,GM(1,1),Background value"
#expected result1 : [ "Forecasting", "GM(1,1)", "Background value" ]

keywords_string2 = "(3E)-4, 8-Dimethyl-1, 3, 7-nonatriene, ultrasonic sprayer"
#expected result2 : [ "(3E)-4, 8-Dimethyl-1, 3, 7-nonatriene", "ultrasonic sprayer" ]
```

Comment: Why don't you have all your names in .txt file and then read names

Comment: Regex probably help you. Or try with .split(", ")  [comma and whitespace]

Comment: Can you guarantee that no independant name starts with a digit? That could be a rule to use for splitting.

Comment: You are in luck if you've a `list` of all possible chemical formulas. You can check the `string` against that `list` to find out whether a chemical formula exists in your string. `in` keyword might help you. Process data further based on the condition.

Comment: That would be humongous list, probably hive on a cluster could manage that. And there are many ways you can write a signle compund. Not feasible.

Comment: @sidx According to Wikipedia, 'As of May 2011, about sixty million chemical compounds are known'... Also, using lists to check if some data is present or not is a bad idea, sets are much better suited for that.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I can only sure there's no number keyword like "3" or "76", but chemicals start with number like  "2,4-D" is existed.

Comment: Probably we can say that a single numer as a keyword is not correct, but to which string concatenate it to? That's harder

Comment: @Shin-BangTsai Well, yes, of course... On the other hand, are there any whose name ends with a digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can be sure that no name ends with a digit (which, as far as I can see, is the case(?)), you could split on commas (and their eventual surrounding spaces) that are not preceded by a digit.

Using a regex to do that, we could do:

```
import re

def split_on_commas(s):
    split_pattern = re.compile('(?<=\D) *, *')
    return split_pattern.split(s)
```

Which gives the expected result on your test cases:

```
keywords_string1 = "Forecasting,GM(1,1),Background value"
#expected result1 : [ "Forecasting", "GM(1,1)", "Background value" ]

print(split_on_commas(keywords_string1))
# ['Forecasting', 'GM(1,1)', 'Background value']


keywords_string2 = "(3E)-4, 8-Dimethyl-1, 3, 7-nonatriene, ultrasonic sprayer"
#expected result2 : [ "(3E)-4, 8-Dimethyl-1, 3, 7-nonatriene", "ultrasonic sprayer" ]

print(split_on_commas(keywords_string2))
#['(3E)-4, 8-Dimethyl-1, 3, 7-nonatriene', 'ultrasonic sprayer']
```

Note that we have to use a positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=\D)` for a non-digit in the regex, so that the non-digit character doesn't get captured as part of the splitting pattern.

Comment: Thank you! This solution works fine. Can you please explain what does (?<=\D) means? I've looked into manual but still confused.